# Selector doesn't work after change it programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, button, text, colors

I have the following problem. I have an App with different colorthemes.
In the middle of an colored Layout is a button with white corners and white text.

**Button:**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
          android:textColor="@color/buttontextcolor_green"
            />
```

**selector_button:**

```
<selector
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
</selector>
```

button_on/off just have stroke and solid attributes to make the button complete white while pressing.

The problem is with the **buttontextcolor_green:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="@color/md_white_1000" />

<item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/greenPrimary"/>

<item   android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/greenPrimary" />

<item   android:color="@color/md_white_1000" />
```

everything works fine, I pressing the `Button`, the button fills white and the `textcolor` change from white to green while pressing.

But after I change the `drawable` of the `android:textColor` from my button programmatically it won't.

**I sad it in the beginning of my Question, I work with multible colorthemes. So if I press the button then `backgroundcolor` of my `Layout` should change and I have to change the textcolor drawable of my button too.**

```
lBackground.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluePrimary));
button.setTextColor((getResources().getColor(R.color.buttontextcolor_blue)));
```

Next time, when I press button,  `textcolor` have to be blue, but it isn't. The `textcolor` stays white on every next click. Just only first click after starting the app works correct.

I apologize if something of my text is incorrect in speech, my german is better!^^

greetings

Comment: as you remove selector and apply one color only `button.setTextColor((getResources().getColor(R.color.buttontextcolor_blue)));` thats why it is not working

Comment: buttontextcolor_blue is a xml file, same as buttontextcolor_green just with other colors in the item attributes.

Comment: But I see the problematic, I can't use a selector from the colors folder? Previously it was in the drawable folder but than I get an compilererror because of using a drawable in setTextColor method.

Comment: just use getColorStateList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getColorStateList`. It will resolve your issue.

change line `button.setTextColor((getResources().getColor(R.color.buttontextcolor_blue)));`

to

> button.setTextColor ( getResources ().getColorStateList (
>   R.color.buttontextcolor_blue)));

and put buttontextcolor_blue color inside color resource folder, as  /res/color/buttontextcolor_blue.xml